# Get image from ImageView, with Databinding

Tags: java, android, android-databinding

I have a basic profile screen, with some TextViews and one ImageView, backed up by a model that binds to each View in the resource file.

I have created a `BindingAdapter`, that will read the profile image as a Base64Encoded string from the model, and place it into the ImageView.

My question is, how would I bind the Bitmap in the ImageView, to the property on my User model, when the user clicks save?  At the moment, all text fields are properly sent through, but I am not sure how to handle the Bitmap in ImageView.

Here is my resource layout file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout>
<data>
    <variable name="user" type="Models.User" />
    <variable name="viewActions" type="ViewModel.ProfileViewModel" />
</data>

<LinearLayout xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal|top">

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progressPostUser"
        android:layout_width="120dp"
        android:layout_height="120dp"
        android:visibility="gone"/>

    <include layout="@layout/main_toolbar"/>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imagePlaceHolder"
        android:layout_width="250dp"
        android:layout_height="150dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:imageBitmap="@{user._profileImage}"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp">

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/btnOpenCamera"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:src="@mipmap/ic_account"
            android:onClick="@{(view) -> viewActions.OnCamerarClicked(view)}"/>

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/btnChooseImage"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:src="@mipmap/ic_view_list"/>

    </LinearLayout>

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="250dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:hint="Name"
        android:text="@={user._name}"/>

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="250dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:hint="Surname"
        android:text="@={user._surname}"/>

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="250dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:hint="Email"
        android:text="@={user._email}"/>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Save"
        android:onClick="@{() -> viewActions.onSaveClicked(user)}"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Here is the click event where I would like to receive the the Bitmap from my ImageView.  As mentioned, all TextView text values are received here:

```
public void onSaveClicked(User user) {
    try {

        PostParams postParam = new PostParams();
        postParam.setmPostObject(user);
        postParam.setmUrl(new URL("http://blahblah.com/AddUser"));

        new AsyncTaskPost(mProfiler).execute(postParam);
    }
    catch (Exception ex) {
        Log.d("ProfileViewModel", ex.getMessage());
    }
}
```

And finally, my `User.java` model.

```
public class User extends BaseObservable {

public User() {

}

private String _name = "";
@Bindable
public String get_name() {
    return _name;
}
public void set_name(String _name) {
    this._name = _name;
    notifyPropertyChanged(BR._name);
}

private String _surname = "";
@Bindable
public String get_surname() {
    return _surname;
}
public void set_surname(String _surname) {

    this._surname = _surname;
    notifyPropertyChanged(BR._surname);
}

private String _email = "";
@Bindable
public String get_email() {
    return _email;
}
public void set_email(String _email) {

    this._email = _email;
    notifyPropertyChanged(BR._email);
}

private Bitmap _profileImage;
public Bitmap get_profileImage() {
    return _profileImage;
}
public void set_profileImage(Bitmap _profileImage) {
    this._profileImage = _profileImage;
}

public String toJsonString(){
    JSONObject jObject = new JSONObject();
    try{
        jObject.put("Name", get_name());
        jObject.put("Surname", get_surname());
        jObject.put("Email", get_email());
        jObject.put("ProfileImage", Base64.encodeToString(convertBitmapToBytes(), Base64.DEFAULT));
    } catch (Exception ex){
        Log.d("Error", "User.toJson");
    }
    return jObject.toString();
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return super.toString();
}

private byte[] convertBitmapToBytes(){
    ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    //get_profileImage().compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);
    return stream.toByteArray();
}
```

}

Comment: Doesn't the User object already contain the correct bitmap?

Comment: @Uli No, the the Bitmap is not data bound.  Do you have an example of how I can bind the Image in the ImageView (Taken from Camera) to the profileImage property in User?

Comment: You need to populate the ImageView from the model, not the other way round.

Comment: @Uli So two way data binding is not possible on an ImageView?  As you can see in my post, I wrote a BindingAdapter that would bind the Base64 to the ImageView, but how to get data from ImageView to property in User?  I have a work around, but not sure if this is how it is supposed to be done

Comment: It's an awful design. You gotta populate the model first. Two-way binding is good for EditText, because you capture the user input, but there is no user input on an ImageView. You shouldn't populate the ImageView directly from your camera image handler; the handler should rather populate the model, and then the ImageView will follow.